# Postgis nested query trouble

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am having difficulty writing a nested postgis query. I have a single table from which I need to create a view in PostgreSQL.

I have created the view with the following command

```sql
create view rrop08.rrop08_lws_f AS
select * from rrop08.rrop08_gk3_polygon 
where planznr='04.01' OR planznr ='04.02';
```

The problem here is that the table contains another field called "bez". I need to carry out the first query but also with bez=0; so that none of the 04.01 or 04.02 rows have a bez value other than 0.

I have tried this...

```sql
create view rrop08.rrop08_lws_f AS
select * from rrop08.rrop08_gk3_polygon 
where planznr='04.01' OR planznr ='04.02' AND bez=0;
```

but this retrieves all rows with bez=0 and not just the 04.01 or 04.02 ones. I need to first select 04.01 or 04.02 and then on this query get those with bez=0...ie.nested.

I´m a bit lost on how to do this.

THanks for any help,

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parenthesis to group the logical expressions or they usually get [evaluated](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) from left to right like you experienced:

```
create view rrop08.rrop08_lws_f AS select * from rrop08.rrop08_gk3_polygon where (planznr='04.01' OR planznr ='04.02') AND bez=0;
```